# Image to world projection

Tags: intrinsics, point-clouds, perspectivecamera, projection-matrix, extrinsic-parameters

I have a RGB image and 8-bit depth data of the same scene from two different cameras and need to generate point cloud in 3D space.

I used [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5743033&tag=1) to understand how to do it.

As mentioned in Eq. 1 we can find non-homogeneous coordinates of the world point w.r.t a pixel in the image as follows,

[image]

Eq. 5 shows how to find the lamda1 as follows,

[image]

Then to find the real depth values based on the 8-bit depth values in the depth image, I used the following Eq. 4 from [this paper](http://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/ivp/2008/438148.pdf),
[image]

So, I expected two point clouds generated from the data from two cameras to align with each other since I used the projection matrices, but the points clouds does not coincide with each other and generated awkward results. Could some kindly point out where is the problem is?

Comment: Each camera has its own world origin?

Comment: Camera locations are known. I projected back to world coordinates, but those point clouds doesn't match with each other. Is that mean, each camera has its own world origins?